# How do i display images from my database? (php)

Tags: php, search-engine

I have setup an image table in my database to store my images as blob type. My problem is that i do not know how to display the images in the db from my web search page. Anytime i enter a searh query, it will display the keyword & the image name but it will not display the image itself. rather it displays long sql codes.

Here are my php codes for Imagesearch.php;

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
</style>
<?php

//get data
$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];
$x = "";
$construct = "";
if (!$button){
    echo "You didint submit a keyword.";
}
else{
    if (strlen($search)<=2) {
            echo "Search term too short.";
    }
    else {
            echo "You searched for <b>$search</b><hr size='1'>";

            //connect to database
            mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("searchengine");



                    //explode our search term
                    $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);

                    foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {

                            //constuct query
                            $x++; 
                            if ($x==1) {
                                    $construct .= "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                            }
                            else {
                                    $construct .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                            }
                    }

                    //echo out construct

                    $construct = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE $construct";
                    $run = mysql_query($construct) or die(mysql_error());

                    $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

                    if ($foundnum==0) {
                            echo "No results found."; 
                    }
                    else {
                            echo "$foundnum results found!<p>";
                            while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
                                    //get data
                                    $name = $runrows['name'];
                                    $image = $runrows['image'];


                                    echo "
                                    <b>$name</b><br>
                                    $image<br>

                                    ";
                            }
                    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should have used Google... [Link](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/7663-tutorial-storing-images-mysql-php-part-ii-display-your-images.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate php script that will return the image itself, and then you will need to call that from your PHP script.

The other PHP script needs to set the Content-type header to the proper mime type.

Answer (score 0):

You should make another script, at another URL, that accepts an ID through a get parameter to output the image.  Could then do something along the lines of:

```
<?php
// ..your MySQL stuff

function error() {
    echo "There was an error";
}

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = (int) $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = '$id'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if (mysql_num_rows() == 1) {
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        // Change this to the correct image type for your stored data
        header("Content-type: image/gif");
        echo $data['image'];
    } else {
        error();
    }
} else {
    error();
}
```

You'd then echo:

```
echo "<b>$name</b> <img src='theimagescript.php?id={$id}' alt='Image of $name' />";
```